# plugin not working for adding post to page

Tags: plugins

This is my first post and rather my first plugin attempt. Am trying to make a plugin which will create a custom post type and will add the post under a page...to achieve this I have managed he following code:

```
function register_cpt_music_review() {

    $labels = array(
        'name' => _x( 'Music Reviews', 'music_review' ),
        'singular_name' => _x( 'Music Review', 'music_review' ),
        'add_new' => _x( 'Add New', 'music_review' ),
        'add_new_item' => _x( 'Add New Music Review', 'music_review' ),
        'edit_item' => _x( 'Edit Music Review', 'music_review' ),
        'new_item' => _x( 'New Music Review', 'music_review' ),
        'view_item' => _x( 'View Music Review', 'music_review' ),
        'search_items' => _x( 'Search Music Reviews', 'music_review' ),
        'not_found' => _x( 'No music reviews found', 'music_review' ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => _x( 'No music reviews found in Trash', 'music_review' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => _x( 'Parent Music Review:', 'music_review' ),
        'menu_name' => _x( 'Music Reviews', 'music_review' ),
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'description' => 'Music reviews filterable by genre',
        'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'trackbacks', 'custom-fields', 'comments', 'revisions', 'page-attributes' ),
        'taxonomies' => array( 'genres' ),
        'public' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_in_menu' => true,
        'menu_position' => 5,
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-format-audio',
        'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'can_export' => true,
        'rewrite' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post'
    );

    register_post_type( 'music_review', $args );
}

add_action( 'init', 'register_cpt_music_review' );

function genres_taxonomy() {
    register_taxonomy(
        'genres',
        'music_review',
        array(
            'hierarchical' => true,
            'label' => 'Genres',
            'query_var' => true,
            'rewrite' => array(
                'slug' => 'genre',
                'with_front' => false
            )
        )
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'genres_taxonomy');

function create_music_review_pages()
  {
   //post status and options
    $post = array(
          'comment_status' => 'open',
          'ping_status' =>  'closed' ,
          'post_date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
          'post_name' => 'music_review',
          'post_status' => 'publish' ,
          'post_title' => 'Music Reviews',
          'post_type' => 'page',
    );
    //insert page and save the id
    $newvalue = wp_insert_post( $post, false );
    //save the id in the database
    update_option( 'mrpage', $newvalue );
  }
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'create_music_review_pages');
```

Now this code allows me to create custom post type and the page also. But on clicking over the page am not able to see the posts.

Any help on this please...am totally new to wordpress

Comment: Is there a reason why you're creating a page to display your custom post type, as opposed to using native post type archives?

Comment: A "page" is just another post type with its own content set in the editor. Why it should be show a list of your custom post type? Also, you should know that any public custom post type (as your custom post type is) has an archive list auto generated in `http://yoursite.com/custom-post-type-slug`. To make a page show something different from its content you have to alter the normal behaviour, maybe using a custom page template, a shortcode, `pre_get_posts` action, `template_include` filter and maybe a lot of other ways. Try to make some more research.

Comment: @cybmeta...thanks for your reply...so am just asking (it may sound very naive) how to display all my posts under music reviews category